# What should I expect in a meeting with the Postgraduate student coordinator as an international PhD applicant?

Tags: graduate-admissions, australia

I am a PhD applicant to Australia in STEM. I had preliminary meetings with my potential supervisors and have already submitted my application.
However, today one of them informed me that the postgraduate student co-ordinator wants to meet with me as the next stage of my application process.

The application deadline is not over yet and they don't release offers before November.

So I was curious as to what I should expect in the meeting? What role do they play in admissions and scholarship offers?